# Llenar un input de tipo datetime-local con una funcion JavaScriipt

Tags: javascript

mi intención es que tu puedas elegir una fecha y hora usando el calendario que te proporciona el campo pero esto puede ser un pesado si tienes prisa, entonces queria un boton que al pulsarlo me llene el campo con la fecha y hora actual del sistema, he usado la siguiente funcion pero no me funciona.

Html:

```
<input type="datetime-local"  v-model="inicio"  class="form-control">
<button type="button" @click="completarHoraInicio()">Completar Automaticamente</button>
```

Función

```
completarHoraInicio(){
    var fecha = new Date(); //Fecha actual
    var mes = fecha.getMonth()+1; //obteniendo mes
    var dia = fecha.getDate(); //obteniendo dia
    var ano = fecha.getFullYear(); //obteniendo año
    var hora = fecha.getHours(); //obteniendo hora
    var minutos = fecha.getMinutes(); //obteniendo minuto

    this.inicio=dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano+" "+hora+":"+minutos;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a SOes! Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona el sitio y así de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular una pregunta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida. Por favor, copia el código en formato texto/código las imagenes con código no ayudan a la pregunta puesto que hay gente que no las puede ver correctamente ademas de que haces mas difícil que te respondan,

Comment: errores que te da?

Comment: solución en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript

Comment: Ya edite la publicacion, ahi puedes ver el aviso que me da

Comment: El  codigo en formato texto por favor ....

Comment: Tienes un error en el `var dia=fecha.GetDate();`, debería ser `var dia=fecha.GetDay();`

Comment: Si pongo getDay() me pilla el número de la semana, getDate() ya hace lo que necesito, igual gracias por tu aporte

Comment: He añadido una respuesta, ten en cuenta que mi respuesta es en `javascript` y por lo que veo en tu código usas algún otro framework que no has indicado en las etiquetas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como en el error indica tienes que poner la fecha en el formato indicado. [Datetime-local input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)

Formato:

> yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm

Tienes que tener en cuenta que si estamos en el mes `1` tienes que rellenar este numero para que tenga 2 digitos: `01`

```js
function completarHoraInicio(){
    var fecha = new Date(); //Fecha actual
    var mes = fecha.getMonth()+1; //obteniendo mes
    var dia = fecha.getDate(); //obteniendo dia
    var ano = fecha.getFullYear(); //obteniendo año
    var hora = fecha.getHours(); //obteniendo hora
    var minutos = fecha.getMinutes(); //obteniendo minuto

    document.getElementById("dateInput").value=ano+"-"+minTwoDigits(mes)+"-"+minTwoDigits(dia)+"T"+minTwoDigits(hora)+":"+minTwoDigits(minutos);
}

function minTwoDigits(n) {
  return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local"  v-model="inicio" id="dateInput" class="form-control">
<button type="button" onclick="completarHoraInicio()">Completar Automaticamente</button>
```

---

Para mas información sobre el formato existe una pregunta en SO donde también se explica que esta caracteristica esta deprecada: [input datetime value format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854874/input-type-datetime-value-format)

Comment: Valee muchisimas gracias, si lo tenia en cuenta eso, estaba buscando algun tipo de get para que me pase el formato con el 0 delante pero no encontraba nada.Si estoy usando laravel y vue , es la primera pregunta que hago aqui asi que no se muy bien que necesita realmente la gente, de nuevo muchas graciaas !!